# Run stored procedures in other schemas from stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-12c, parallelism

I have a current process: a large procedure in one schema.
There is a plan to have `A, B1, B2, B3` schemas (B-schemas are identical, could be B-n schemas) in Oracle 12c database.
Schemas `B1, B2, B3` have synonyms to A.
Schema `A` stores all the connections information to other schemas.

Is it possible to run a stored procedure in `A` and call the stored procedure in other `B`-schemas (dynamically determine schemas to run and do it in parallel).

There is also .Net part and it is better to put this logic there and make calls to the `B`-schemas stored procedure in different threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can call procedures in schema B from procedures in schema A. Depending on the version of Oracle, you may have to grant execute privileges on each procedure explicitly from B to A, using the "with grant" option, rather than through a role. Consult documentation for your specific version to verify what permissions are required.

In general I would also recommend putting orchestration logic into the back-end (database) rather than client-side code. Keep your back-end and front-end business logic separate.